How would I allow user credentials to be passed into a HTML iframe?
I'm working on a small project at work which uses a local HTML file which contains a iframe and some javascript to change the contents of the iframe every 30 seconds. However, when I provide a specific link to an internal platform, I get prompted with login credentials. If I enter the credentials, I get taken back to the login screen again.
I've done some digging around the internet, that I need to pass the basic auth through the iframe so the website can be logged into. I've seen a few solutions about doing https://user:pass@website.com, but that doesn't work and Chrome shows a Subresource requests whose URLs contain embedded credentials are blocked. It seems like this has been disabled/deprecated in most modern browsers as it poses a security risk. But as this is just internal, is there a way around this?
